# Django: Unable To Replace The Default User Model With Custom User Model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0, django-custom-user

I am unable to replace default django user model with my own custom user model.
yes, i have `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appName.modelName'` set in `settings.py`

here's my code

**`settings.py`**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'userProfile',
'user_authorisation',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEl = 'userProfile.myUser'
```

`userProfile/models.py`
https://dpaste.de/Aerm

`userProfile.forms.py` https://dpaste.de/0eOO

`userProfile/admin.py` https://dpaste.de/Rm5S

After all this, Default user model is still showing in django admin
and also, when creating super user via the command `python manage.py createsuperuser` , it is creating the super user of the default user model.

Comment: Did you first migrate the application? So `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`.

Comment: there was a typo AUTH_USER_MODE'l'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's typo in your settings `AUTH_USER_MODEl`, should be `AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead.